# MAUI. Implementing Entry inside collection view and change some behaviours

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

i'm having problem with a feature in an entry control and I don't known how to face it.

I have an endpoint that returns a list of an object class, and one property is defined as decimal? and I have to show it in an entry, because you can edit that value.

My first problem is that I have to show values with only one decimal digit. First approach was setting StringFormat in Text Entry's property to 0:F1, but when I write inside that Entry, it works very bad. Second approach was to implement behaviours and using NumericValidationBehavior from MAUI toolkit, but it crashes when property is null. Third approach was to use Math.Round in .ForMember from Mapper, but it didn't work.

My second problem is that, in the same Entry, I need to set one decimal digit, I mean, I if write "1", then displays "1", if I write "12", then displays "1.2", if I write "123" then displays "12.3". For that, I tryied to implement TextChanged event, but in iOS I found that cursor position didn't work as expected.

Code from TextChanged is like this.

```
if (!(sender is TextField entry)) return;

        // Desconecta temporalmente el manejador para evitar bucles infinitos
        entry.TextChanged -= TextField_TextChanged;

        var textoOriginal = e.OldTextValue;
        var textoNuevo = e.NewTextValue.Replace(".", ""); // Elimina cualquier punto existente

        // Verifica que haya suficientes caracteres para insertar un separador decimal
        if (textoNuevo.Length > 1)
        {
            textoNuevo = textoNuevo.Insert(textoNuevo.Length - 1, "."); // Inserta el punto en la penúltima posición
        }

        entry.Text = textoNuevo;

        // Calcula la nueva posición del cursor
        var nuevaPosicionCursor = textoNuevo.Length;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoOriginal) && textoNuevo.Length > textoOriginal.Length)
        {
            // Ajuste adicional si es necesario, por ejemplo, cuando se inserta un caracter y se añade el punto automáticamente
            nuevaPosicionCursor = textoNuevo.Length;
        }

        entry.CursorPosition = nuevaPosicionCursor;          
        //entry.CursorPosition++;

        // Reconecta el manejador del evento
        entry.TextChanged += TextField_TextChanged;
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the string to the int and modify the number. Here is the demo you can refer to.

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var text = e.NewTextValue;
     float final;
     var text1 = float.Parse(text);

     if (text1 >= 10 && text1%10==0 ) {
         
         final = (float)(text1 / 10 + text1 % 10 * 0.1);
         entrynum.Text = final.ToString();

     }
  /*   else if ( text1 < 10)
     {
         final = text1;
         entrynum.Text = final.ToString();

     }*/
   

 }
```

Comment: Perhaps I haven't expressed myself properly, what I need is for the decimal separator to be automatically entered. If I want to enter '342.4', I will have to enter '3424'. It doesn't seem very complex, but I'm having trouble getting it to work properly, as the cursor position is lost and it puts it in the middle of the number. Additionally, that Entry can load data and obviously it will go through the TextChanged event.

Comment: Yes, but if you change the text in the entry, it will call the `TextChanged` event once.